# Widmer "Brrr" clone

Tags: recipe, clone-recipe

Has anyone found a decent clone recipe for the Widmer 'Brrr' seasonal? This is the second year I've seen it in their sample 12 packs. But in the sample pack, it only has 3 'Brrr's, I'd like to make more, if anyone has a recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ingredients found on beeradvocate I tossed them in BrewR to get the numbers close.

This should be a good start to a clone recipe.

**Widmir Brrr**

Batch size: 12.0 gal

Boil volume: 13.5 gal

OG: 1.072

FG: 1.018

Bitterness (IBU): 51.2

Color (SRM): 16.9

ABV: 7.0%

**Grain/Sugars:**

15.00 lb Two-row (US), 44.8%

15.00 lb Munich (German), 44.8%

1.00 lb Crystal 80L, 3.0%

1.00 lb Crystal 10L, 3.0%

1.00 lb CaraPils, 3.0%

0.50 lb Chocolate Malt (US), 1.5%

**Hops:**
2.00 oz Magnum (AA 12.0%, Pellet) 90 min, 32.7 IBU

2.00 oz Cascade (AA 6.6%, Pellet) 30 min, 12.9 IBU

1.00 oz Simcoe (AA 12.0%, Pellet) 10 min, 5.5 IBU

Comment: Wow, I didn't know beeradvocate had ingredient lists. I'll have to keep that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Just and FYI @CDspace BeerAdvocate happens to have the ingredients for this beer. They don't have ingredients for beers as a rule.  A quick search at widmerbrothers.com shows the same ingredient list.  Many breweries do have the ingredients and enough info to try and piece it together like Evil did here.  Its good stuff.

Comment: @brewchez I understand they might not have ingredients for every beer, but it's at least a place to start before posting here